# Any idea why this works seamlesly in HTML/CSS, but in wordpress nothing?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a feature that I am trying to add to a clients wordpress site and when I add the html in the editor just as I have it here. It works like here:[DEMO](http://www.joshuadavidinc.com/din8/ourrestaurants/). Everything seems to work brilliantly in just html and CSS, but in wordpress, not so much. I have added the code here as well for your review.

```css
 body {
   background-color: #777;
 }
 .slide-panel {
   position: relative;
   font-family: Arial;
 }
 .slide-panel-content {
   background-color: #333;
   position: fixed;
   right: -573px;
   width: 431px;
   height: 80%;
   border-radius: 8px;
   padding: 0 20px 20px 20px;
   transition: all 0.3s ease;
 }
 .slide-panel-tab {
   background: hsla(75, 100%, 41%, 1.0);
   color: hsla(100, 100%, 100%, 1.0);
   padding: 5px;
   display: block;
   position: fixed;
   top: 150px;
   right: -60px;
   transition: all 0.3s ease;
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
   transform: rotate(-90deg);
   display: inline-block;
   border: none;
   z-index: 0;
   cursor: pointer;
 }
 input[type="checkbox"] {
   display: none;
 }
 input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label + .slide-panel-content {
   right: 0;
 }
 input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label {
   right: 412px;
 }
```

```html
<body>

  <div id="slide-panel" class="slide-panel">

    <input type="checkbox" id="checker" type="button" value="feedback">

    <label for="checker" class="slide-panel-tab">

      <p style="text-align:center;">BECOME A PARTNERING
        <br />RESTAURAUNT</p>

    </label>

    <div class="slide-panel-content">

      <div data-area="input">

        <div class="content">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- close: slide-inner -->
  </div>
  <!-- close: slide-panel-content -->
</body>
```

Comment: Where in Wordpress are you adding this code? To a template?

Comment: Those elements aren't picking up the css at all. Have you added it correctly in to a css file that is linked?

Comment: I am adding it into the WYIWYG editor, but nothing. I have a CSS file named custom.css that is linked and all of the other CSS reads fine. I have CSS from the nav menus in there as well. This is quite odd.

Comment: you need to add that css to a css file and add the file to your template/header using http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_style (probably like you do for custom.css) you might as well use a html/css snippet plugin like https://wordpress.org/plugins/insert-html-snippet/

Comment: I already have the CSS in a file called "custom.css" which is created for extra CSS that the site may need. I am only placing the html in the WYSIWYG editor.

Answer (score 0):

Where you have add this CSS ?

Please add this css in **theme-styles.css** at the end

do inspect element in chrome you will see that your styling is not coming.

Comment: I have the CSS in a file called custom.css. It's very strange that it's not picking up, because my navigation styles are in there and it picks those up fine.

Comment: [custom css](http://www.joshuadavidinc.com/din8/wp-content/themes/dinate/custom.css) does not content this please add there

Comment: I'm sorry what do you mean?

Comment: i checked your **custom.css** but it does not content you above Css. So please check that.

Comment: Yes, it's very weird. I added it in there and aged it multiple times to both files and it will not show up.  It doesn't save. Any idea why?

Comment: add this css to main style.css

Comment: No matter what the css will not save in any file? Any idea what that could be?

Comment: just for try. put this css in the page.php or if front page then front_page.php

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't work. I don't have enough points to add this as a chat, so could you do so?

Comment: ranasoyab@gmail.com plese add me in your gmail and we will chat there.

Comment: I did and messaged you!

Answer (score 0):

Its working for me, i have created a test page in backend and paste the html code there inside editor (please check for content formatting in wp editor, sometimes it takes unnecessary

& 
 tags)

```
<div id="slide-panel" class="slide-panel">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checker" type="button" value="feedback">
    <label for="checker" class="slide-panel-tab">
     <p style="text-align:center;">BECOME A PARTNERING <br />RESTAURAUNT</p>
   </label>
<div class="slide-panel-content">
  <div data-area="input">
    <div class="content">
    </div>
  </div>
 </div><!-- close: slide-inner -->
</div>
```

and also CSS in style.css
and then i have created a test template with this code

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Test Template
*/

get_header();

if(have_posts()):while(have_posts()):the_post();

the_content();

endwhile;endif;
get_footer();
?>
```

and set the test template for test page, and slide panel works for me.

Comment: In my theme I can't add anything to the style.css Everything is set up in the theme-style.css i can give you my login to the page and you can try it, but I can't get anything to work for me. I have tried every suggestion on this thread. Would you be able to do that? It seems that no matter where I add the css, it doesn't save or show up....